# Tablesorter filter plugin + filter widget: Filtering/searching results that are not currently displayed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

**EDIT: As it turns out, my pager js file was outdated - it's not included in the downloadable tablesorter zip file, and apparently I found and was using a rather old version.**

I am trying to recreate the table found in [this example](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-filtered.html) using my own table. Currently I'm at a point where the pager is working and the filter is working as well, except for a single **core functionality** required for my own table. This functionality is the ability to filter on a single record which is not currently displayed. For example, in the linked example of Mottie you can filter the name column on '25', and it will show that single row with Student25 - even though you were previously only displaying the first 10 results. It is vital for my table's filtering to filter through all rows/records, even though I am only displaying a small margin of them at that time. **How do I filter through all my rows/records even though I am displaying a specific number of records that does not currently contain the row(s)/record(s) I'm looking for, like in the example of Mottie?**

My JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


// **********************************
//  Description of ALL pager options
// **********************************
var pagerOptions = {

    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
    container: $(".pager"),

    // use this url format "http:/mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}"
    ajaxUrl: null,

    // modify the url after all processing has been applied
    customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) { return url; },

    // process ajax so that the data object is returned along with the total number of rows
    // example: { "data" : [{ "ID": 1, "Name": "Foo", "Last": "Bar" }], "total_rows" : 100 }
    ajaxProcessing: function(ajax){
        if (ajax && ajax.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
            // return [ "data", "total_rows" ];
            return [ ajax.total_rows, ajax.data ];
        }
    },

    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'
    // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
    output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})',

    // apply disabled classname to the pager arrows when the rows at either extreme is visible - default is true
    updateArrows: true,

    // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
    page: 0,

    // Number of visible rows - default is 10
    size: 10,

    // Save pager page & size if the storage script is loaded (requires $.tablesorter.storage in jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js)
    savePages : true,

    //defines custom storage key
    storageKey:'tablesorter-pager',

    // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many records are displayed. The space is made up by an empty
    // table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
    fixedHeight: true,

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
    removeRows: false,

    // css class names of pager arrows
    cssNext: '.next', // next page arrow
    cssPrev: '.prev', // previous page arrow
    cssFirst: '.first', // go to first page arrow
    cssLast: '.last', // go to last page arrow
    cssGoto: '.gotoPage', // select dropdown to allow choosing a page

    cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
    cssPageSize: '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option

    // class added to arrows when at the extremes (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
    cssDisabled: 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
    cssErrorRow: 'tablesorter-errorRow' // ajax error information row
};

$("table")
            .bind('filterInit', function() {
            // check that storage ulility is loaded
            if ($.tablesorter.storage) {
                // get saved filters
                var f = $.tablesorter.storage(this, 'tablesorter-filters') || [];
                $(this).trigger('search', [f]);
            }
            })
            .bind('filterEnd', function(){
                if ($.tablesorter.storage) {
                    // save current filters
                    var f = $(this).find('.tablesorter-filter').map(function(){
                        return $(this).val() || '';
                    }).get();
                    $.tablesorter.storage(this, 'tablesorter-filters', f);
                }
            })

    // Initialize tablesorter
    // ***********************
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
                    headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
                    widgetOptions: {

                        // zebra widget: adding zebra striping, using content and
                        // default styles - the ui css removes the background
                        // from default even and odd class names included for this
                        // demo to allow switching themes
                        // [ "even", "odd" ]
                        zebra: [
                            "ui-widget-content even",
                            "ui-state-default odd"
                            ],

                        // uitheme widget: * Updated! in tablesorter v2.4 **
                        // Instead of the array of icon class names, this option now
                        // contains the name of the theme. Currently jQuery UI ("jui")
                        // and Bootstrap ("bootstrap") themes are supported. To modify
                        // the class names used, extend from the themes variable
                        // look for the "$.extend($.tablesorter.themes.jui" code below
                        uitheme: 'jui',

                        // columns widget: change the default column class names
                        // primary is the 1st column sorted, secondary is the 2nd, etc
                        columns: [
                            "primary",
                            "secondary",
                            "tertiary"
                            ],

                        // columns widget: If true, the class names from the columns
                        // option will also be added to the table tfoot.
                        columns_tfoot: true,

                        // columns widget: If true, the class names from the columns
                        // option will also be added to the table thead.
                        columns_thead: true,

                        // filter widget: If there are child rows in the table (rows with
                        // class name from "cssChildRow" option) and this option is true
                        // and a match is found anywhere in the child row, then it will make
                        // that row visible; default is false
                        filter_childRows: false,

                        // filter widget: If true, a filter will be added to the top of
                        // each table column.
                        filter_columnFilters: true,

                        // filter widget: css class applied to the table row containing the
                        // filters & the inputs within that row
                        filter_cssFilter: "tablesorter-filter",

                        // filter widget: Customize the filter widget by adding a select
                        // dropdown with content, custom options or custom filter functions
                        // see http://goo.gl/HQQLW for more details
                        filter_functions: null,

                        // filter widget: Set this option to true to hide the filter row
                        // initially. The rows is revealed by hovering over the filter
                        // row or giving any filter input/select focus.
                        filter_hideFilters: false,

                        // filter widget: Set this option to false to keep the searches
                        // case sensitive
                        filter_ignoreCase: true,

                        // filter widget: jQuery selector string of an element used to
                        // reset the filters. 
                        filter_reset: ".reset",

                        // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching;
                        // This option prevents searching for every character while typing
                        // and should make searching large tables faster.
                        filter_searchDelay: 300,

                        // filter widget: Set this option to true to use the filter to find
                        // text from the start of the column. So typing in "a" will find
                        // "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false
                        filter_startsWith: false,

                        // filter widget: If true, ALL filter searches will only use parsed
                        // data. To only use parsed data in specific columns, set this option
                        // to false and add class name "filter-parsed" to the header
                        filter_useParsedData: false,

                        // Resizable widget: If this option is set to false, resized column
                        // widths will not be saved. Previous saved values will be restored
                        // on page reload
                        resizable: true,

                        // saveSort widget: If this option is set to false, new sorts will
                        // not be saved. Any previous saved sort will be restored on page
                        // reload.
                        saveSort: true,

                        // stickyHeaders widget: css class name applied to the sticky header
                        stickyHeaders: "tablesorter-stickyHeader"

                    }
    })

    // initialize the pager plugin
    // ****************************
    .tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);

        });
```

Using these .js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When working with ajax data, any sorting or filtering must be done by your server.

To pass the correct data to your server, the `ajaxUrl` option needs to be set up to post the sort column(s), sort directions, and any filter (by column).

The demo linked in the question is meant for tables that already contain all rows. For an ajax example, see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html). Notice that the `ajaxUrl` is shown above the table and is updated as you interact with the table. *Sadly, this demo is not attached to an actual database, so sorting and filtering do not work.*

Once the server gets the sort & filter data and sends it back to the browser, the [`ajaxProcessing` function](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing) can then manipulate the data for rendering.

I hope that clears up your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I feel you're pointing at something that doesn't solve my issue - allow me to add a few pieces of information:
1) My table already contains all rows (let's say 50). I retrieved them from my DB and populated my table with its values. So the situation is identical to your example (the I mentioned in the OP).
2) Both the pager and the filter are working properly, except for that specific feature I mentioned that does work in your example (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-filtered.html).

Comment: So to summarize: I want to filter on results that are not currently paged/displayed. This works in your example, but not in my code - even though most parts are identical; a table that contains all rows, working pager and working filter (except for that feature).